# variable is not a member of class

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm running a loop to add rows to a data table from an array list filled with products. I can get the first object item, however the following ones are bringing the below issue:

> Error BC30456 'itemName' is not a member of 'Product'

Stepping through the solution I can see that the array does actually contain the object items I want to display.

```
Product class
public class Product
{
private int itemQuantity { get; set; }
public string itemID { get; set; }
private string itemName { get; set; }
private string itemCategory { get; set; }
private double itemPrice { get; set; }
private string itemDescription { get; set; }


public Product()
{
}

public Product(string ID, string name, string category, double price, string description)
{
    itemID = ID;
    itemName = name;
    itemCategory = category;
    itemPrice = price;
    itemDescription = description;
    itemQuantity = 1;
}
}
```

and my method to add rows to the data table

```
Public Sub createShoppingCartTable()

    Dim tableColumnCode As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnCode
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        .ColumnName = "ProductCode"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnCode)

    Dim tableColumnName As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnName
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        .ColumnName = "Name"
        .DefaultValue = "unknown"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnName)


    Dim tableColumnQuantity As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnQuantity
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        .ColumnName = "Quantity"
        .DefaultValue = "1"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnQuantity)

    Dim tableColumnPrice As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnPrice
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        .ColumnName = "Price"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnPrice)

    Dim tableColumnTotalPrice As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
    With tableColumnTotalPrice
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        .ColumnName = "TotalPrice"
        .DefaultValue = "0"
    End With
    ShoppingCartTable.Columns.Add(tableColumnTotalPrice)


    'create rows with products added to cart
    Dim tableRow As System.Data.DataRow = ShoppingCartTable.NewRow()
    Dim intMaxRows As Integer = shoppingCart.Count - 1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim localObj As New Product()

    For i = 0 To intMaxRows
        localObj = shoppingCart(i)
        tableRow = ShoppingCartTable.NewRow()
        tableRow("ProductCode") = localObj.itemID
        tableRow("Name") = localObj.itemName
        tableRow("Quantity") = localObj.itemQuantity
        tableRow("Price") = localObj.itemPrice
        tableRow("TotalPrice") = localObj.itemQuantity * localObj.itemPrice
        ShoppingCartTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
    Next

    Me.dgDatagrid.DataSource = ShoppingCartTable
    Me.dgDatagrid.DataBind()
End Sub
End Class
```

My solution shows up the itemID correctly, however everything after that fails with the above error.

Comment: What type is `shoppingCart` (in camelCase) and where is it initialized?

Comment: shoppingCart is initialised in the page load of the page the method is located. Do I need to convert it into C# and put it in the Product class?

Comment: I asked you what type it is. Sounds like it is a `Product[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is the matter of the the access modifiers (`public` / `private`). Try to change the `private` keywords in the `Product` class to `public`

Comment: Dammit I forgot I changed that! How bloody obvious